# iOS9 and initWithPattern with iPad Pro causing repeating background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, background, ios9

I now upgraded to iPad Pro simulator for iOS9 and now I am getting a repeating background.  Is there something new I must do in order to get the image to correctly expand on iPad Pro.  My image sizes dont have a new launch image so I am lost on this.

```
- (void)addBackgroundImage:(NSString*)imageName {
    UIColor *image = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = image;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `CGImage` in background to avoid repeating background.

### Objective-C

```
self.view.layer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)([UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImageAsset"].CGImage);
```

### Swift

```
self.view.layer.contents = UIImage(named:"backgroundImageAsset").CGImage
```